# how are XGboost parameters tuned

Tags: r

I was recently given a task to evaluate the XGBoost model. The parameters of the model looks something like this

```
 Parameters:'eta':0.5,'max_depth':25,'subsample':1,'colsample_bytree':0.8,'objective':'reg:linear','eval_metric':'rmse','booster':'gbtree','n_estimators':100000
```

I was just wondering, if the depth 25 would really overfit the test data,because you are introducing complexity in the model.

25 depth means 2^25 number of nodes?

Also `n_esimators` value is 100000, will that also cause overfitting?

I just want to understand the parameters and how are they related?

Comment: indeed this does look like an unfortunate set of hyper parameters. Also high `eta`, no regularization via `gamma`, `alpha` or `lambda`. How a set of hyper pars will perform needs to be evaluated on hold out data. But the posted does not look like it should be evaluated at all.

Comment: Have you read through the documentation? That's the best place to start when you want to "understand the parameters and how are they related". It's a pretty vague, open-ended question for SO. I'd suggested digging and reading a bit, and coming back if you have specific confusions.